# Find the root for the function $2+x^{2}-x^{3}$

Tags: roots

How do we prove that the root for $$2+x^{2}-x^{3}$$ exits in the interval $[2,3]$??

Comment: no it isn't, we will get 2 by inserting -1

Comment: are you sure?$$ 2+1+1\neq 0$$

Comment: You don't prove that, since it isn' true.

Comment: You cannot because it is not true.

Comment: @onelessproblem I advise you to delete this question.

Comment: Why? is it too basic for this community?

Answer (score 3):

There is no root in the interval $(2,3)$.

[image: cubic]

To argue there is a root in $(1,2)$:

1. Polynomials are continuous.
2. $f(1)=2 >0$
3. $f(2)=-2 < 0$

Therefore, the function must have at least one $0$ value in the interval.

---

The root lone real root is $f\left( x_{0} \right) = 0$ with 
$$
x_{0} = \frac{1}{3} \left(\sqrt[3]{28 + 3 \sqrt{87}}+\sqrt[3]{28-3 \sqrt{87}}+1\right) \approx 1.69562
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=2+x^2-x^3$. Since $$f'(x)=2x-3x^2=(2-3x)x<0$$ when $x\in (2,3)$, $$f(x)<f(2)=-2$$ for any $x\in (2,3)$.

So there is no root.